# Laravel 9 - map collect can't scope outside variable array even using use

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-collection

why `map` it's not returning or pushing a values into array i tried to use `use function` to call my `array Emails` but its not working here is my logic code

```
   $emails = []; //emails array

    $students = User::where('role','student')->get();   //10 students email

    $maps = collect($students)->pluck('email'); //collect 10 students email

    $maps->map(function($map) use($emails){
        return  array_push($emails, $map); //push 10 students email to emails array
    });

    return $emails; //test emails array
```

it is returning empty email array i don't know why its not working

Comment: Try with `use(&$emails)`, otherwise a basic `foreach($maps as $email) { array_push($emails, $email); }` might work better.

Comment: Or, ditch _all_ of that, and just do `return collect($students)->pluck('email')->toArray();` 

Comment: &emails i used this now its working fine now thank you, kind a weird that adding &

Comment: Yeah, adding `&` is [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). It means you can modify the variable inside of the function without having to return/reassign it (in a nutshell; there's a lot more happening behind the scenes with that)

Comment: thanks for the info.. first time to encounter that " & "

Comment: No problem! First time I saw it I'm pretty sure I said "what the ..." too  Cheers, and happy coding!

Comment: @RayParas be careful when accepting or using ChatGPT generated answers. There's no way a normal user can post 8 long answers in 30 minutes. ChatGPT answers look well written but the actual technical details can be completely wrong.